# When I turn on "design mode", I do not need to type the password for the specific worksheet. How can I modify this code to solve this problem?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to password protect a worksheet named "Import". It is important that the content is hidden. I have used the code below, and it works fine. The only problem is that when I stand in another sheet and turn on design mode, I am no longer required to type in the password (ex: Test123).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Range("A65536").Select
'change the password here (ABC)
If InputBox("What is the password?", "Password") = "Test123" Then
Range("A1").Select
Else
MsgBox ("Password incorrect")
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The event doesn't fire when in design mode. Does the sheet still have to be visible?

Comment: Nope, but I prefer to have it visible

Comment: As a note, a user could also easily circumvent this by turning events off: `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the immediate window. Excel doesn't really have "foolproof" security. Just a thought.